# PHP : How to transform JSON keys into value

Tags: php, json

I have this form of json  
:{"1":"7.00","2":"8.00"} 
 
How can i transform it in  this type of json?  
{{"id":"1","qty":"7.00"},{"id":"2","qty":"8.00"}} 
 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First is to `json_decode()` your JSON.
- Now, you have an array with keys as IDs and values as quantities.
- Iterate over the array and insert into the result with `id` and `qty` as keys.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$str = '{"1":"7.00","2":"8.00"}';
$data = json_decode($str,true);

$result = [];

foreach($data as $key => $val){
    $result[] = [
        'id' => $key,
        'qty' => $val
    ];
}

echo json_encode($result);
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/8VS4t